# Bootstrap Modal doesn't popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Below is the code which I copied from the Bootstrap website. I can't understand why is it not working, even though it works on its website as a demo.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my script and link tags for bootstrap

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

How should I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load jquery before bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Check the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpsLfgzn/1/
This works like a charm with your code.

Comment: Bro, Earlier when bootstrap was loaded before jquery nothing showed up. I took your suggestion and loaded jquery above the bootstrap. When I click on the `Launch Demo` button the background becomes blur but nothing pops up.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Can you maybe post your new example here?

Comment: this is the jsfiddle version of my code. https://jsfiddle.net/MeetOG/wozcrsdk/7/ It works on the fiddle but doesn't work on my system. How is that?

Comment: Well depends, what your system means. How are your files structures? When do you load the scripts, when do you try to access the handler? When do you assign the handler? etc.
Can you check it in in any repository on GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap = style library + a bunch of jQuery plug-ins

By the way, if you just need the bootstrap style, you don't have to introduce JS files for jQuery and bootstrap at all

Comment: But for a modal you need jquery and bootstrap.js